# Restore backup from pgadmin 3 to 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-3, pgadmin-4

Is there an easy way to restore databases from PGadmin 3 into Pgadmin 4? Right now data on both, and I want to gather all my data on the same server. The port on PGadmin 3 is 5432 and 5433 on PGadmin 4. My PostgreSQL versions is 10.1 on pgadmin 3 and 11.3 on pgadmin 4.

Previously, with help I succeeded in doing so by using Notepad++, but I can't figure out how we did then.

Comment: Your apparent mix-n-match of administration tool names and database instance references is confusing (especially using pgAdmin-III to manage a 10.1 instance), but this is really in the proper domain of [dba.se].

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this documentation [Backup and Restore](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/backup_and_restore.html)

> A powerful, but user-friendly Backup and Restore tool provides an easy way to use pg_dump, pg_dumpall, and pg_restore to take backups and create copies of databases or database objects for use in a development environment.
>
> Using the pg_dump utility, pgAdmin provides an easy way to create a backup in a plain-text or archived format. You can then use a client application (like psql or the Query Tool) to restore a plain-text backup file, or use the Postgres pg_restore utility to restore an archived backup. The pg_dump utility must have read access to all database objects that you want to back up.

[image]

> The Restore dialog provides an easy way to use a Custom, tar, or Directory format backup taken with the pgAdmin Backup dialog to recreate a database or database object. The Backup dialog invokes options of the pg_dump client utility; the Restore dialog invokes options of the pg_restore client utility.

[image]

Comment: I have tried this more than once. I think the problem for me is how I change the port from 5432 to 5433?